# How to accept payload of multipart type using HapiJs API?

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, hapi.js

I have implemented one POST API using Nodejs module Hapijs. While I am passing an image using postman using 'form-data' type, I am getting following error:

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Invalid multipart payload format"}
```

If somebody has solution for the same then please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This Format this will surely work for you maxBytes is the size which you want maximum bytes to get upload.

```
 payload:{
            maxBytes:30485760,
            parse: true,
            output: 'file',
            allow: 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        validate: {
            payload: {
                accessToken: Joi.string().required(),

                profilePic: Joi.any()
                    .meta({swaggerType: 'file'})
                    .description('image file')
                    .required(),


            }
```